# How Can I access supportActionBar from Inside fragment_name.kt Source File with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

In my `MainActivity.kt` file, I can access `supportActionBar.title` and set the title.

In `TitleScreenFragment.kt`, I cannot access:

```
activity.supportActionBar.title
```

and when I try to just use `activity.actionBar.title`, that value is null.

**How do I access `activity.supportActionBar.title` from within my fragment code?**

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



    val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this,
        R.layout.activity_main)

    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

    //THIS WORKS HOW DO I ACCESS THIS FUNCTIONALITY FROM FRAGMENT CODE???
    supportActionBar?.title = "Ingredient Display"
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp()
}
```

}

**TitleScreenFragment.kt**

```
    class TitleScreenFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Setup the binding object with the layout and inflate it

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragTitleBinding>(inflater, R.layout.frag_title, container, false)

    // Set navigation action as an onclicklistener for button
    binding.btnBeginInput.setOnClickListener{
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_titleScreenFragment_to_ingredientInputFragment)

    }

    //THIS IS NULL
    println(activity?.actionBar?.title)

    // return the inflated object in the binding

    return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Ingredient Display"
```

in the `onViewCreated` method (not in `onCreateView`).

Comment: Sweet man thanks. That worked perfectly. I am learning Kotlin and android at the same time. What is that behavior called when you:

(activity as AppCompatActivity)?

Is that casting? By the way this worked but don't stop here everyone, I believe there are better ways to set actionbar titles as other posts have mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Aaron yes it is a casting.